# Share point error "the tagging service is unavailable, please try later"

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

whenever i put a hashtag and try to write something i am getting this error msg:-
"the tagging service is unavailable, please try later" i googled a lot and got couple of solutions 
1)issues with memory leakage, tried but error persist
2) Tag service might be not enabled.
can some one please tell me from where to enable this service in detail or any other solution

Answer (score 0):

This is part of a SharePoint Service Application called **Managed Metadata service**. You manage that in a tool called Central Administration. You typically have to be a Farm Administrator to get access to that tool.

In Central Admin, go to Application Management --> Manage Service Applications. If you don't see Managed Metadata Service listed, you need to add it, http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12713.sharepoint-2013-how-to-configure-managed-metadata-service.aspx.